# Typescript: Generic Function to extract only defined values from a specific key from an Array of Objects

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I've got two functions which do exactly the same thing so it seems like a prime candidate for a generic function to replace them. However I can't quite get it right, the extracted value isn't exactly the same as the original type as the return type should be the original result/error type but now without undefined.

```
type Value = string;

type PurchaseResult = {
  result: Value | undefined,
  error: Error | undefined, 
}
```

One of the existing examples of the function (for the other function replace key and type with result/value:

```
const extractErrors = (
  purchaseResults: PurchaseResult[]
) =>
  purchaseResults
    .map(({ error }) => error)
    .filter((error): error is Error => Boolean(error));
```

Failed Attempt

```
        const extractOnlyDefinedValuesFromArrayOfObjects = <
          T,
          K extends keyof A,
          A extends { [k in K]: T }
        >(
          list: A[],
          key: K
        ): T[] =>
          list
            .map((obj) => obj[key])
            .filter((value) => typeof value !== 'undefined');

        const extractedResults = extractOnlyDefinedValuesFromArrayOfObjects<
          Value,
          'result',
          PurchaseResult
        >('result', arrayOfResults);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax `Value || undefined` is not allowed, use `|` instead.
I don't know whether you have defined type `Value` or not, that's why I have added `T` generic - for `Value`;

Consider this example:

```js
type PurchaseResult<Value> = {
  result: Value | undefined,
  error: Error | undefined,
}

const extractErrors = <
  T,
  Key extends keyof PurchaseResult<T>,
  Data extends PurchaseResult<T>[]
>(
  purchaseResults: Data,
  key: Key,
) =>
  purchaseResults
    .map(elem => elem[key])
    .filter((elem): elem is NonNullable<Data[number][Key]> => Boolean(elem));

declare let results: PurchaseResult<number>[]

const result = extractErrors(results, 'result') // number[]
const result2 = extractErrors(results, 'error') // Error[]
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mqQeZm)

I have used `Data` just to alias `PurchaseResult<T>[]`. Since we have appropriate generic for our list, we can use `NonNullable<Data[number][Key]>` for our typeguard

Answer (score 1):

A generalised version that accepts any array of key-value pairs and returns a typed array of values for the specified key, extracted from each record.  ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-vJMpzllW6Y1p2Qa9+iIIZHyfUC30PT9YG-X9mFzPh1nAIA))

```js
/**
 * extractKey extracts record[key] from an array of records 
 * @param key - a key in records
 * @param records - an array of key-value records of the same type
 * @return - `key` for each record, where record[key] is defined.
*/
const extractKey = <T extends Record<string, any>, K extends keyof T>(
  key: K,
  records: T[]
): Array<NonNullable<T[K]>> => {
    return records
        .map(el => el[key])
        .filter(el => typeof el !== "undefined")
}

// define a type to test on, but can be any key-value pair type
type PurchaseResult = {
  result?: number
  error?: string
}

// some dummy data
const testMe: PurchaseResult[] = [{result: 1}, {error: "no result!"}, {result: 4}]


// test it!
const results = extractKey('result', testMe) // []number

const errors = extractKey('error', testMe) // []string
```